# Absolute positioning element 100% width inside relative positioned container bug in webkit

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, width, absolute

I've used this [positioning trick](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/) a bit to achieve complex outcomes. I think I've come across a bug in webkit browsers which I'm struggling to understand.

Here is the simple markup:

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <div>
            <span class="cols-6"></span>
        </div></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

and CSS:

```
*, *:after, *:before {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}

table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}
tr {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
td {
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100px;
    border: solid #ddd;
    border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
    box-shadow: -1px 0px #ddd;
}
td div {
    position: relative;
}
td div span.cols-6 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 600%;
    height: 20px;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

To see this in action, open up this http://jsfiddle.net/JFxqt/14/ in chrome.

The displayed span is absolutely positioned inside a relative container. As the table uses fixed layout, its cells are all fixed width, hence a child should be able to make use of a percentage width. The table has 7 columns while the span's width is set to 600% (i.e. 6 columns * 100%). It fails to cover all 6 columns in webkit browsers. Firefox and IE renders fully across all specified columns.

Ideally setting the span's width to 100% should render across 1 column, 200% across 2 columns and so on.

Anyone have any ideas or workarounds?

Comment: It looks like you are creating a CSS framework, so am I correct in assuming that you will have styles like `.cols-1`, `.cols-2` ... `.cols-10` and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a day or two searching for workarounds it would seem a conditional JS enhancement for Webkit browsers is the only viable solution.

The problem stems from Webkits (and Opera's old rendering engine) calculation of percentage widths, which are always rounded down to the nearest pixel as opposed to being stored as a double. Therefore in Webkit a 1px descrepancy may be added for every factor of 100% (eg 2300% - 100% * 23 - will have a maximum of 23px discrepancy), while Firefox and later versions of IE can only have an overall maximum of 1px discrepancy.

John Resig touched on this issue a while ago, http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [http://jsfiddle.net/JFxqt/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/JFxqt/4/)

I changed this around in your CSS:

```
body{margin:0px}
td div {

}
span.cols-6 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 85.6%;
    height: 20px;
    background: #ccc;
    z-index:10;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, not exactly what I was after though. There are 7 columns in the table, the span is meant to cover only 6 of them. It's meant a custom substitute for use in place of colspan. In other words setting it to 400% would be akin to setting colspan of 4.

Comment: There you go not it covers only 6 of the 7 boxes. You just have to change the width to suit what you need

Comment: Thanks again for the response, but your solution requires knowledge of the number of columns specified in the markup. I'm trying to get a solution that works for an arbitrary number of columns regardless of position within the page. i.e. the solution should work equally well with http://jsfiddle.net/JFxqt/6/

Comment: You will need to try some jquery then to do that sort of calculation

Comment: Well that's the thing, I'm trying to figure out a non javascript solution. The CSS I posted should work (works in all non webkit browsers), just wondering if there's something I'm missing to get webkit to play ball or if it's an inherent bug with webkit's rendering engine?

Comment: I think the problem is that it just does not like what you are trying to do. So you may need to try a new solution

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing a cross-browser issue related to how the widths of table cells are computed and inherited.  This may be either a bug or something that is not specified explicitly by the CSS specifications and left to the browser to decide.

In Firefox, the width of `<td>` is inherited by the `<div>` whereas in the webkit (Chrome) browser, the width inherited by the child `<div>` is 1px smaller.

When you multiply by 100% and 200%, you won't see an effect, but by the time you get to the last cell at 700%, you see about a 7px gap.

If you are building a CSS framework, you will need to create a style for Firefox browsers and another for webkit browsers.

For the case of 6 columns, I found the following would work:

```
td div span.cols-6 {
    position: absolute;
    left:-1px;
    width: 600%;
    border-right: 6px solid #ccc;
    height: 20px;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

I add a right border that is 600% x 1px = 6px and then position the span to the left by -1px.  For another number of columns, for example, `.cols-3`, you would need `width: 300%` and `border-right: 3px solid #ccc` and so on.

You may need to use some type of a CSS filter or selector hack.  I did find the following reference: http://browserhacks.com

No clean or elegant solution for this problem unfortunately.

Comment: I have seen the `calc` function but have not tried it.  It may not be that well supported yet.  Do you absolutely need tables?  The problem is due to how the browsers do the maths around table cell widths... tough to work around this.

Comment: Thats exactly what I thought Marc though it appears even more annoying than that. You can make use of the new css3 calc function to do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/JFxqt/10/.

However, even that still doesn't yield desired results. When you resize your window. Watch the bar are you resize your browser/container on jsfiddle.

Comment: I see what you mean.  Can you tell me how the gray bar will be used? what type of content will it contain? What kind of flexibility/fluid/responsive behavior do you need?

Comment: Yes unfortunately, the same problem exists building a more complex div based solution and using display:table display:table-cell etc.

I may be out of luck though, can't think of any workarounds that seem to work for webkit.

Comment: Why does the gray bar have to be embedded inside the table?

Comment: It's an attempt at building a custom rowspan/colspan implementation that allows a calendering widget to be rendered naturally inline (single cell) or previewed as a multi-column event (without resorting to javascript or markup changes)

Comment: I guess you are trying to avoid doing something like `<td colspan=6>`?

Comment: Exactly that, if we actually use proper colspans and rowspans, we would have to render two sets of markup (one flat & one grouped).